# How to remove the last comma from each line in a string?

Tags: python, strip

I have a variable called `output` that stores this string:

> Numbers: 1, 2, 3, 4,
>
> Numbers1: 1, 3, 5, 7,
>
> Numbers2: 2, 4, 5, 7,

How to remove ONLY the last comma in each line?
Result should look like this:

> Numbers: 1, 2, 3, 4
>
> Numbers1: 1, 3, 5, 7
>
> Numbers2: 2, 4, 5, 7

`output.rstrip(',')` only strips the last comma in Numbers2 like this:

> Numbers: 1, 2, 3, 4,

> Numbers1: 1, 3, 5, 7,

> Numbers2: 2, 4, 5, 7

`output[:-1]` results in the same and only strips the last line

Comment: Is this a dictionary? Please provide in code format

Comment: As you said, it's a single string. It has embedded newlines, so you need to split the string into multiple strings first.

Comment: Can you please share the relevant code?

Comment: How did you *get* the single string in the first place?

Comment: I got the single string by making 2 for loops that add "Numbers" + "1, " + "2, "... to and empty string named output = "" and then printed the whole output at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not too good in terms of performance if your string is very long, but it should do

```py
"\n".join(x[:-1] for x in output.splitlines())
```

Comment: this didn't affect the output

Comment: @Dani_K `output = "\n".join(x[:-1] for x in output.splitlines())`

Comment: oh my bad, there was a whitespace right after the comma. Changed it to [:-2] and it works thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can probably combine multiple rstrips if you have mixed endings, but the best answer is to use regular expressions.

```
import re
output =  "1,2,3,4 \t\n"
print(re.sub(",\s*$", "", output))
```

outputs

```
1,2,3,4
```

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/223634/206609

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "1, 2, 3, 4,"
s1=s[:-1] # it returns all characters except the last (-1 counting from the end).
```

```
In : s1                                                                   
Out: '1, 2, 3, 4'
```

Comment: I added the comment.

Comment: the problem is that output is a big single string and this would only remove the comma in the last line

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to remove every comma for each midline and substring for the last one.

```
import re
string = """Numbers: 1, 2, 3, 4,

Numbers1: 1, 3, 5, 7,

Numbers2: 2, 4, 5, 7,"""
final = re.sub(r',[\s]+N', '\nN', string)[:-1]
print(final)
```

Output

> Numbers: 1, 2, 3, 4
>
> Numbers1: 1, 3, 5, 7
>
> Numbers2: 2, 4, 5, 7

Comment: This one only removes the comma from the last line. I had problems to recreate how I got the string.

Comment: No. It removes every comma as I put in the example because use a regular expression to replace the comma followed by whitespace and N. And finally, removes the last one. Try it.

Comment: Well, that means your string is different to what I put in the example.